# AngularJS scope

Tags: angularjs

I have run into a issue when trying to reference models with angularjs. I can get some of them to reference, but others are not working. I've included the code below:

```
function DeleteCustomers($scope, func) {
     $scope.delete = function() {
         func.deleteCustomer($scope.customer);
     }
 }


function UpdateCustomers($scope, func) {
    $scope.update = function() {
        func.updateCustomer({ name: $scope.name2, telephone: $scope.telephone2,
            email: $scope.email2, street: $scope.street2,
            city: $scope.city2, zipcode: $scope.zipcode2 });
        }
    }
}
```

And the html is

```
<div ng-controller="UpdateCustomers">
       <form class="test-angular-update">
           <input type="text" ng-model="name2"><br>
           <input type="text" ng-model="telephone2"><br>
           <input type="text" ng-model="email2"><br>
           <input type="text" ng-model="street2"><br>
           <input type="text" ng-model="city2"><br>
           <input type="text" ng-model="zipcode2"><br>
           <button class="button" ng-click="update()">Update</button><br>
       </form>
   </div>

   <br><br>
   <div ng-controller="DeleteCustomers">
       <form class="text-angular-delete">
           Customer Name <input type="text" ng-model="customer"><br>
           <button class="button" ng-click="delete()">Delete</button><br>
       </form>
   </div>
```

All the models from UpdateCustomers and DeleteCustomers are not being able to be referenced by the controllers. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not quite clear what your problem is, and your code is too incomplete to make a guess. Could you provide a jsFiddle that demonstrates the issue better?

Comment: The problem is that the ng-models under UpdateCustomers and DeleteCustomers are not being resolved. Thus, I cannot access them via $scope like I can with the other models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a more solid application structure, which might help ensure the func service is injected properly. Not sure if that's the issue you're having.

```
//app.js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

//services.js
app.factory('func', function(){/* service code*/});

//controllers.js
app.controller('DeleteCustomers', ['$scope', 'func', function($scope, func){
   $scope.delete = function() {
     func.deleteCustomer($scope.customer);
   };
}]);//edit had typo here missing ']'
```

EDIT: Working demo http://jsfiddle.net/grendian/Um3pR/

Comment: this is what I put `Module.controller('DeleteCustomers', [ '$scope', 'func', function($scope, func) {
           $scope.delete = function() {
               func.deleteCustomer($scope.customer);
           };
    }]);`   no luck.

Comment: Edited original to fix type and include working demo. See if that helps.